# Drop Shadow On Text EditorX Wix

Tags: text, velo, dropshadow, dropshadoweffect

I am trying to add a drop shadow to text on editor x.

I have been trying this over and over again with different SO posts and tutorials and for some reason, it does not work /. show up the shadow. Here is what I am doing:

```
$w.onReady(function () {

$w("#type").html =`<h2 style='word-spacing:4px;filter:text-shadow(1px 1px 5px #000000)'>` + ​​​​​​​​​$w("#type").text + `</h2>`;

})
```

I also tried another version that also does not seem to work:

```
$w.onReady(function () {

$w("#type").html =`<h2 style="text-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #000; class="font_2 wixui-rich-text__text">Test Title Test Title</h2>`;

})
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

I tried changing syntax, calling on different elements and also two different ways of giving a shadow. But all of them do not show up on the site when I hit publish.